# Ubuntu - PHP Multibyte Extension

Tags: 14.04, php

I have installed the PHP mutlibyte extension for PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu server 14.04 however the application that requires it says it is uninstalled, the application is IPS.

Running `php -m` shows mbstring under the list of PHP modules.

I installed it using `sudo apt-get install php-mbstring` and the installer
completed successfully

**Result of** `php -m`**:**

[image: php -m]

Answer (score 2):

make sure to restart your web server. if you are using apache you can restart it like so:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

For **PHP 7.4, 8.0, 8.1** use the following commands to install:

```
apt install php7.4-mbstring php8.1-mbstring -y
```

And restart **Apache2** server finally:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

*P.S. Tested on Debian 10+ & Ubuntu 20.04+*